# Link opens only when its full size

Tags: html, responsive-design

I have created a responsive website  ([www.openlabs.ai](http://www.openlabs.ai)) and under `our product` section I have placed a link to open a page in new tab.
 The problem I am facing is that the link opens only when the browser window size is full if I make the browser/chrome window smaller and then try to open the link, nothing happens. I tried to see the problem through google chrome developer tool but I could not find any problem.

```
            <li class="has-children">
              <a href="#about-section" class="nav-link">Our Products</a>
              <ul class="dropdown arrow-top">
                <li><a href="4cast/" target="_blank" class="nav-link"><span
                 class="text-primary">Openlabs:4Cast</span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
```

When I do developers tools of chrome and try to click the the link while keeping the window smaller than full I get the following error.

```
main.js:228 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (main.js:228)
    at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLBodyElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

Looking for solution as well as interested to know the reason why it does not open if the window size is smaller, let's says half sized or on mobile.

PS: I am not a web developer.

[image]

Comment: Please include a [mre] in the question itself. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to do so.

Comment: The website is live, you can check there. Just make the browser window half size and try to open the link.

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552), where the answer is No.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with a function in your main.js.
The function `OnePageNavigation();` is to animate the scroll to a section when you click an anchor with hash. But, the selectors that you are using `.main-menu li a[href^='#'], .smoothscroll[href^='#'], .site-mobile-menu .site-nav-wrap li a` include anchors without hash, for that reason the page is not opened.

Try to remove the selector `.site-mobile-menu .site-nav-wrap li a`.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem, also why it works when the window size is full but does not work if the window size is smaller

Comment: When you click the link appears an error in the console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined` at line 228 in the main.js. So, I think the problem could be there. Also, the menu on the desktop and mobile are separated, the issue could be there too.